# base-files update issue

Tags: apt, upgrade

I am under Ubuntu 22.04 LTS server.
During a "normal" update (eg.apt update + apt dist-upgrade), I read that base-files refused  to update (stayed at 0%) and it crashed all future updates.

I have tried to hold base-files from update with apt-mark but I got the same issue.

How know which module is crashing base-files update ?

Note : I have tested inodes and space on hard disk use is around 15%-20%. So no troubles with this.

```
apt-cache policy base-files
base-files:
  Installé : 12ubuntu4.3
  Candidat : 12ubuntu4.3
 Table de version :
 *** 12ubuntu4.3 500
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     12ubuntu4 500
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
```

To be more clear :

```
sudo apt update
Atteint :1 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Réception de :2 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [119 kB]
Réception de :3 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [107 kB]
Réception de :4 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
Réception de :5 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages [939 kB]
Réception de :6 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages [877 kB]
2 152 ko réceptionnés en 1s (3 036 ko/s)
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances... Fait
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
40 paquets peuvent être mis à jour. Exécutez « apt list --upgradable » pour les voir.

sudo apt list --upgradable
En train de lister... Fait
curl/jammy-updates,jammy-security 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.8 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.7]
fwupd-signed/jammy-updates 1.51~22.04.1+1.2-3ubuntu0.2 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 1.44+1.2-3]
grub-efi-amd64-bin/jammy-updates 2.06-2ubuntu14.1 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 2.06-2ubuntu14]
grub-efi-amd64-signed/jammy-updates 1.187.3~22.04.1+2.06-2ubuntu14.1 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 1.187.2+2.06-2ubuntu14]
grub-efi-amd64/jammy-updates 2.06-2ubuntu14.1 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 2.06-2ubuntu14]
intel-microcode/jammy-updates,jammy-security 3.20230214.0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 3.20220809.0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
isc-dhcp-client/jammy-updates 4.4.1-2.3ubuntu2.4 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 4.4.1-2.3ubuntu2.3]
isc-dhcp-common/jammy-updates 4.4.1-2.3ubuntu2.4 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 4.4.1-2.3ubuntu2.3]
libcurl3-gnutls/jammy-updates,jammy-security 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.8 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.7]
libcurl4/jammy-updates,jammy-security 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.8 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.7]
libgnutls30/jammy-updates,jammy-security 3.7.3-4ubuntu1.2 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 3.7.3-4ubuntu1.1]
libmbim-glib4/jammy-updates 1.28.0-1~ubuntu20.04.1 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 1.26.2-1build1]
libmbim-proxy/jammy-updates 1.28.0-1~ubuntu20.04.1 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 1.26.2-1build1]
libmm-glib0/jammy-updates 1.20.0-1~ubuntu22.04.1 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 1.18.6-1]
libnss3/jammy-updates,jammy-security 2:3.68.2-0ubuntu1.2 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 2:3.68.2-0ubuntu1.1]
libpq5/jammy-updates,jammy-security 14.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 14.6-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
libqmi-glib5/jammy-updates 1.32.0-1ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 1.30.4-1]
libqmi-proxy/jammy-updates 1.32.0-1ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 1.30.4-1]
libsasl2-2/jammy-updates 2.1.27+dfsg2-3ubuntu1.2 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 2.1.27+dfsg2-3ubuntu1.1]
libsasl2-modules-db/jammy-updates 2.1.27+dfsg2-3ubuntu1.2 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 2.1.27+dfsg2-3ubuntu1.1]
libsasl2-modules/jammy-updates 2.1.27+dfsg2-3ubuntu1.2 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 2.1.27+dfsg2-3ubuntu1.1]
linux-generic/jammy-updates,jammy-security 5.15.0.67.65 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 5.15.0.60.58]
linux-headers-generic/jammy-updates,jammy-security 5.15.0.67.65 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 5.15.0.60.58]
linux-image-generic/jammy-updates,jammy-security 5.15.0.67.65 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 5.15.0.60.58]
modemmanager/jammy-updates 1.20.0-1~ubuntu22.04.1 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 1.18.6-1]
postgresql-14/jammy-updates,jammy-security 14.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 14.6-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
postgresql-client-14/jammy-updates,jammy-security 14.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 14.6-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
python-apt-common/jammy-updates 2.4.0ubuntu1 all [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 2.4.0]
python3-apt/jammy-updates 2.4.0ubuntu1 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 2.4.0]
python3-distupgrade/jammy-updates 1:22.04.16 all [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 1:22.04.15]
python3-software-properties/jammy-updates 0.99.22.6 all [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 0.99.22.4]
shim-signed/jammy-updates 1.51.3+15.7-0ubuntu1 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 1.51+15.4-0ubuntu9]
software-properties-common/jammy-updates 0.99.22.6 all [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 0.99.22.4]
sudo/jammy-updates,jammy-security 1.9.9-1ubuntu2.3 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 1.9.9-1ubuntu2.2]
systemd-hwe-hwdb/jammy-updates 249.11.3 all [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 249.11.2]
tar/jammy-updates,jammy-security 1.34+dfsg-1ubuntu0.1.22.04.1 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 1.34+dfsg-1build3]
tcpdump/jammy-updates 4.99.1-3ubuntu0.1 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 4.99.1-3build2]
ubuntu-advantage-tools/jammy-updates 27.13.6~22.04.1 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 27.13.5~22.04.1]
ubuntu-release-upgrader-core/jammy-updates 1:22.04.16 all [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 1:22.04.15]
update-notifier-common/jammy-updates 3.192.54.5 all [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 3.192.54]
```

And to finish :

```
sudo apt dist-upgrade
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances... Fait
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Calcul de la mise à jour... Fait
Les NOUVEAUX paquets suivants seront installés :
  linux-headers-5.15.0-67 linux-headers-5.15.0-67-generic linux-image-5.15.0-67-generic linux-modules-5.15.0-67-generic linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-67-generic
Les paquets suivants ont été conservés :
  grub-efi-amd64 grub-efi-amd64-bin grub-efi-amd64-signed systemd-hwe-hwdb
Les paquets suivants seront mis à jour :
  curl fwupd-signed intel-microcode isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common libcurl3-gnutls libcurl4 libgnutls30 libmbim-glib4 libmbim-proxy libmm-glib0 libnss3 libpq5 libqmi-glib5 libqmi-proxy libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules
  libsasl2-modules-db linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic modemmanager postgresql-14 postgresql-client-14 python-apt-common python3-apt python3-distupgrade python3-software-properties shim-signed
  software-properties-common sudo tar tcpdump ubuntu-advantage-tools ubuntu-release-upgrader-core update-notifier-common
36 mis à jour, 5 nouvellement installés, 0 à enlever et 4 non mis à jour.
1 partiellement installés ou enlevés.
14 standard LTS security updates
Il est nécessaire de prendre 0 o/146 Mo dans les archives.
Après cette opération, 604 Mo d'espace disque supplémentaires seront utilisés.
Souhaitez-vous continuer ? [O/n] O
Extraction des modèles depuis les paquets : 100%
Préconfiguration des paquets...
Paramétrage de base-files (12ubuntu4.3) ...

Progression : [  0%] [..................................................................................................................................................................................................]
```

It stays at 0%...

---

To be more clear :

```
sudo apt update
Atteint :1 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Réception de :2 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [119 kB]
Réception de :3 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [107 kB]
Réception de :4 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
Réception de :5 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages [939 kB]
Réception de :6 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages [877 kB]
2 152 ko réceptionnés en 1s (3 036 ko/s)
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances... Fait
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
40 paquets peuvent être mis à jour. Exécutez « apt list --upgradable » pour les voir.

sudo apt list --upgradable
En train de lister... Fait
curl/jammy-updates,jammy-security 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.8 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.7]
fwupd-signed/jammy-updates 1.51~22.04.1+1.2-3ubuntu0.2 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 1.44+1.2-3]
grub-efi-amd64-bin/jammy-updates 2.06-2ubuntu14.1 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 2.06-2ubuntu14]
grub-efi-amd64-signed/jammy-updates 1.187.3~22.04.1+2.06-2ubuntu14.1 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 1.187.2+2.06-2ubuntu14]
grub-efi-amd64/jammy-updates 2.06-2ubuntu14.1 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 2.06-2ubuntu14]
intel-microcode/jammy-updates,jammy-security 3.20230214.0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 3.20220809.0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
isc-dhcp-client/jammy-updates 4.4.1-2.3ubuntu2.4 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 4.4.1-2.3ubuntu2.3]
isc-dhcp-common/jammy-updates 4.4.1-2.3ubuntu2.4 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 4.4.1-2.3ubuntu2.3]
libcurl3-gnutls/jammy-updates,jammy-security 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.8 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.7]
libcurl4/jammy-updates,jammy-security 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.8 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.7]
libgnutls30/jammy-updates,jammy-security 3.7.3-4ubuntu1.2 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 3.7.3-4ubuntu1.1]
libmbim-glib4/jammy-updates 1.28.0-1~ubuntu20.04.1 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 1.26.2-1build1]
libmbim-proxy/jammy-updates 1.28.0-1~ubuntu20.04.1 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 1.26.2-1build1]
libmm-glib0/jammy-updates 1.20.0-1~ubuntu22.04.1 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 1.18.6-1]
libnss3/jammy-updates,jammy-security 2:3.68.2-0ubuntu1.2 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 2:3.68.2-0ubuntu1.1]
libpq5/jammy-updates,jammy-security 14.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 14.6-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
libqmi-glib5/jammy-updates 1.32.0-1ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 1.30.4-1]
libqmi-proxy/jammy-updates 1.32.0-1ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 1.30.4-1]
libsasl2-2/jammy-updates 2.1.27+dfsg2-3ubuntu1.2 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 2.1.27+dfsg2-3ubuntu1.1]
libsasl2-modules-db/jammy-updates 2.1.27+dfsg2-3ubuntu1.2 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 2.1.27+dfsg2-3ubuntu1.1]
libsasl2-modules/jammy-updates 2.1.27+dfsg2-3ubuntu1.2 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 2.1.27+dfsg2-3ubuntu1.1]
linux-generic/jammy-updates,jammy-security 5.15.0.67.65 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 5.15.0.60.58]
linux-headers-generic/jammy-updates,jammy-security 5.15.0.67.65 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 5.15.0.60.58]
linux-image-generic/jammy-updates,jammy-security 5.15.0.67.65 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 5.15.0.60.58]
modemmanager/jammy-updates 1.20.0-1~ubuntu22.04.1 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 1.18.6-1]
postgresql-14/jammy-updates,jammy-security 14.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 14.6-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
postgresql-client-14/jammy-updates,jammy-security 14.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 14.6-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
python-apt-common/jammy-updates 2.4.0ubuntu1 all [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 2.4.0]
python3-apt/jammy-updates 2.4.0ubuntu1 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 2.4.0]
python3-distupgrade/jammy-updates 1:22.04.16 all [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 1:22.04.15]
python3-software-properties/jammy-updates 0.99.22.6 all [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 0.99.22.4]
shim-signed/jammy-updates 1.51.3+15.7-0ubuntu1 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 1.51+15.4-0ubuntu9]
software-properties-common/jammy-updates 0.99.22.6 all [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 0.99.22.4]
sudo/jammy-updates,jammy-security 1.9.9-1ubuntu2.3 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 1.9.9-1ubuntu2.2]
systemd-hwe-hwdb/jammy-updates 249.11.3 all [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 249.11.2]
tar/jammy-updates,jammy-security 1.34+dfsg-1ubuntu0.1.22.04.1 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 1.34+dfsg-1build3]
tcpdump/jammy-updates 4.99.1-3ubuntu0.1 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 4.99.1-3build2]
ubuntu-advantage-tools/jammy-updates 27.13.6~22.04.1 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 27.13.5~22.04.1]
ubuntu-release-upgrader-core/jammy-updates 1:22.04.16 all [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 1:22.04.15]
update-notifier-common/jammy-updates 3.192.54.5 all [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 3.192.54]
```

And to finish :

```
sudo apt dist-upgrade
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances... Fait
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Calcul de la mise à jour... Fait
Les NOUVEAUX paquets suivants seront installés :
  linux-headers-5.15.0-67 linux-headers-5.15.0-67-generic linux-image-5.15.0-67-generic linux-modules-5.15.0-67-generic linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-67-generic
Les paquets suivants ont été conservés :
  grub-efi-amd64 grub-efi-amd64-bin grub-efi-amd64-signed systemd-hwe-hwdb
Les paquets suivants seront mis à jour :
  curl fwupd-signed intel-microcode isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common libcurl3-gnutls libcurl4 libgnutls30 libmbim-glib4 libmbim-proxy libmm-glib0 libnss3 libpq5 libqmi-glib5 libqmi-proxy libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules
  libsasl2-modules-db linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic modemmanager postgresql-14 postgresql-client-14 python-apt-common python3-apt python3-distupgrade python3-software-properties shim-signed
  software-properties-common sudo tar tcpdump ubuntu-advantage-tools ubuntu-release-upgrader-core update-notifier-common
36 mis à jour, 5 nouvellement installés, 0 à enlever et 4 non mis à jour.
1 partiellement installés ou enlevés.
14 standard LTS security updates
Il est nécessaire de prendre 0 o/146 Mo dans les archives.
Après cette opération, 604 Mo d'espace disque supplémentaires seront utilisés.
Souhaitez-vous continuer ? [O/n] O
Extraction des modèles depuis les paquets : 100%
Préconfiguration des paquets...
Paramétrage de base-files (12ubuntu4.3) ...

Progression : [  0%] [..................................................................................................................................................................................................]
```

It stays at 0%...

---

```
apt-cache policy base-files
base-files:
  Installé : 12ubuntu4.3
  Candidat : 12ubuntu4.3
 Table de version :
 *** 12ubuntu4.3 500
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     12ubuntu4 500
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: What's the output of `apt-cache policy base-files`. Is this a brand new install of 22.04? Because I see no updates to `base-files` since August last year. https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/base-files/11ubuntu5.6

Comment: First thx for help...
I think that a file has to be updated or parameterized inside base-files and crashed the update

Comment: I've moved your response to the question, please keep detail there, and perhaps delete your current answer.

Comment: answer done in a 2 new comments

Comment: In a correction to my first comment, the latest base-files for focal is indeed 12ubuntu4.3. https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/base-files/12ubuntu4.3

Comment: Take a look at this answer which may help debug the issue with `base-files` https://askubuntu.com/a/1345804/612

Comment: You should be able to get English message output by running `sudo LANG=C apt dist-upgrade` however `Paramétrage` would translate to `Setting up` I think - in which case the file you need to look at is the base-files package's `.postinst` script, `/var/lib/dpkg/info/base-files.postinst`

Comment: ... see also this possibly related Q [dpgk --configure -a hangs setting up base-files , apparently in systemd-tty-ask-password-agent](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1365845/dpgk-configure-a-hangs-setting-up-base-files-apparently-in-systemd-tty-ask)

Comment: Ok...
I have open and modify : `/var/lib/dpkg/info/base-files.postinst` and add `set -x` and comment the line `deb-systemd-invoke $_dh_action 'motd-news.service' >/dev/null || true`.

After this I have ran a `dpkg --configure -a` and it stops at `update-notifier-motd.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.`.
I stopped the process and re-run `apt update && apt dist-upgrade` and 90% of the update was done. 
 Now it is stopped at `update-notifier-motd.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.`